# Trouble implementing ajax. if statement wont work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, variables, draper

I'm not sure what the problem is here to know what exactly I'm asking but I'll give it my best shot. 
I tried to bold where I think the issues is to make it clearer.

I'm working with ajax for the first time. In the app a user(1) searches for user(2), upon finding user(2) user(1) can click a button 'add relationship' which sends a relationship request to user(2). the button 'add relationship' should change to 'relationship requested' straight away and then upon refreshing the page, the button should change to 'edit relationship'.

'add relationship' = no relationship exists yet
'relationship requested' = pending relationship exists, acts like a success flash message
'edit relationship' = pending relationship exists or accepted relationship exists

It's all working except the last part where **the button should change to 'edit relationship' upon refreshing the browser page. 'add relationship' appears instead**

Any ideas this 'edit relationship' button wont appear? I am using state machine, draper and js-routes gems.

**view/users/index:**

where upon searching for user(2) their name appears and the button to 'add relationship', 'edit relationship' or 'relationship requested' buttons appear next to the name

**the if statement here is what's not working I think. Why isn't it finding the relationship based on if it is pending or accepted?**

```
<% if logged_in? %>
    <ul>
        <% @users.each do |user| %>
            <li>
                <%= user.name %>
                <div id="relationship-status">
                    <% if current_user.following.include?(user.id) || current_user.pending_following.include?(user.id) %>
                        <%= link_to "Edit Relationship", edit_relationship_path(followed_id: user.id), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                    <% else %>
                        <%= link_to "Add Relationship", new_relationship_path(followed_id: user.id), class: "btn btn-primary", id: 'add-relationship', data: { followed_id: user.id.to_param } %>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            </li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

**controller/users:**

```
  def index
    @users = User.search(params[:search])
  end
```

**relationship.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#add-relationship').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var addRelationshipBtn = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: Routes.relationships_path({relationship: { followed_id: addRelationshipBtn.data('followedId') }}),
            dataType: 'json', 
            type: 'POST', 
            success: function(e) {
                addRelationshipBtn.hide();
                $('#relationship-status').html("<a href='#' class='btn btn-success'>Relationship Requested</a>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**model/user:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :pending_relationships,  class_name:  "Relationship",
                                    foreign_key: "follower_id"
  has_many :active_relationships,   class_name:  "Relationship",
                                    foreign_key: "follower_id",
                                    dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :passive_relationships,  class_name:  "Relationship",
                                    foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                    dependent:   :destroy                                
  has_many :following, -> { where(relationships: { state: "accepted" } ) }, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower                              
  has_many :pending_following, -> { where(relationships: { state: "pending" } ) }, through: :pending_relationships,  source: :followed
```

**relationship/decorator:**

```
class RelationshipDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all

  decorates :relationship

  def relationship_state
    model.state.titleize
  end

  def sub_message
    case model.state
    when 'pending'
      "Relationship request pending"
    when 'accepted'
      "You are now connected with #{model.followed.name}"
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT:**

db/migrate:

```
class AddStateToRelationships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :relationships, :state, :string
    add_index :relationships, :state
  end
end
```

model/relationship:

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :followed, class_name: "User"
  validates :follower_id, presence: true
  validates :followed_id, presence: true

  after_destroy :delete_mutual_relationship!

  state_machine :state, initial: :pending do
    after_transition on: :accept, do: [:send_acceptance_email, :accept_mutual_relationship!]

    state :requested

    event :accept do
      transition any => :accepted
    end
  end
```

terminal output:

```
Started POST "/relationships?relationship%5Bfollowed_id%5D=25" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-06 16:35:26 +1100
Processing by RelationshipsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"relationship"=>{"followed_id"=>"25"}}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 25]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (5.4ms)  INSERT INTO "relationships" ("created_at", "followed_id", "follower_id", "state", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-11-06 05:35:26.360104"], ["followed_id", 25], ["follower_id", 1], ["state", "pending"], ["updated_at", "2014-11-06 05:35:26.360104"]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "relationships" ("created_at", "followed_id", "follower_id", "state", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-11-06 05:35:26.368921"], ["followed_id", 1], ["follower_id", 25], ["state", "requested"], ["updated_at", "2014-11-06 05:35:26.368921"]]
  Relationship Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "relationships".* FROM "relationships"  WHERE "relationships"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 49]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 25]]
  Rendered user_mailer/relationship_requested.html.erb (0.2ms)

UserMailer#relationship_requested: processed outbound mail in 27.9ms

Sent mail to example-24@example.com (14.2ms)
Date: Thu, 06 Nov 2014 16:35:26 +1100
From: noreply@example.com
To: example-24@example.com
Message-ID: <545b089e6206e_6c313ff72cf9cf78434189f@example.local.mail>
Subject: Firstname Surname wants to follow you. Please log in to accept
 this request
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hi example-24, 

Firstname Surname wants to follow you.

   (7.7ms)  commit transaction
Completed 200 OK in 71ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 14.4ms)
```

what happens when I (user 1) search for a user example-24 (user id = 25) and then press the 'add relationship' button (as shown in sqlitebrowser: (see the bottom of the image for the 2 rows relevant to this example)

[image: db relationship table]

**EDIT:**

users/controller:

```
  def create
    if params[:relationship] && params[:relationship].has_key?(:followed_id)
      @followed = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
      # @followed = User.where(name: params[:relationship][:followed_id]).first
      @relationship = Relationship.request(current_user, @followed)
      respond_to do |format|
        if @relationship.new_record?
          format.html do
            flash[:danger] = "There was a problem creating that relationship request"
            redirect_to followed_path(@followed)
          end
          format.json { render json: @relationship.to_json, status: :precondition_failed }
        else
          format.html do
            flash[:success] = "Friend request sent"
            redirect_to followed_path(@followed)
          end
          format.json { render json: @relationship.to_json }
        end
      end
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Friend Required"
      redirect_to users_path
    end
  end
```

Comment: have you tried it from the rails console? We don't see your state machine code, or some code where you change the state or some value in the database.
And the dataType is json, which i think maybe 'script'.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @argentum47! how do I try it from the rails console? I'm not sure what you mean by 'the dataType is json, which i think maybe 'script'.'? I'm pretty new to this. I've put up code for the state machine now though (the model and db migration)

Comment: I also just added the terminal output showing what happens when the 'add relationship' button is pressed. it does seem to be processed as JSON. If I use sqlitebrowser I can see 2 relationships have been created upon pressing the 'add relationship' button. I'll add a pic of that to the question now too so you can see it

Comment: You are sending an ajax request, so your dataType should be 'script' not 'json' in your javascript.

Comment: @argentum47 i changed it, the 'relationship request button wont appear anymore, the termainal say's its being processed as html and I'm getting 'SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: ...'

i changed it back to json and I'm still getting 'SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: ...'. now I'm even more lost

Comment: I have posted an answer, see if that works for you, else set up a chat or come to the irc #rubyonrails channel, there are better people than me :P

Comment: @argentum47 how do i get on the irc #rubyonrails channel? I've never heard of it before?

also! I restarted my comp and the sqlite error went away. I tried the script idea again, it processes as JS in the terminal output does everything it use to and starts a get request to show the user i am trying to friend. the view in the browser doesnt change though to still shows 'add relationship'.

Comment: also I'm not sure why but the 'relationship requested' button wont appear anymore when I click 'add relationship' (as it did when I first posted the question) - if I use json or script..

Comment: Do you have a respond_to foramt.js in your controller?

Comment: nope. but that would be if i used script right? if i reverted back to 'json' shouldn't the original behaviour work again? The javascript console in the browser shows: POST http://localhost:3000/relationships?relationship%5Bfollowed_id%5D=44 412 (Precondition Failed)

Comment: if you have json, then u need to write format.json {... }
Do you have a respond_to foramt.js in your controller?
check  if current_user.following.include?(user.id) if this line executes properly, i guess that condition is false, thats why no change of buttons. Rest seems to look fine. https://meblog.herokuapp.com/public/rCDk80M3glDaTo4DzEwSLA steps to join irc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64372/discussion-between-argentum47-and-sss333).

Comment: i added the create action for the user controller then. it's where the respond format part is. I got the 'relationship requested' part to show again by dealing with the precondition part of this action in the else format.json part. the only part not working is the 'edit relationship' button doesn't show when the page is refreshed. it shows 'add relationship' instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I can't fix this error of yours, You can do it like this.

1. Have a `form_for` or `link_to` with an option remote true.
2. A `controller` and a `route` to respond to your `action`

For example:

In your **routes.rb**

```
resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

And in your **relationships_controller.rb**

```
def create
  //find the user_id of the to_be_followed user
  // like User.find(params[:relationship][:user_id] 
  // this :relationship comes from your controller
  // and current_user.relationsihps.create(followed_id: other_user_id)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to user_path(other_user) }
    format.js
  end
end

//similarly
def destroy
  //find the other_user, if relationship exists, destroy it
end
```

And then in your **html**

__ _follow.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(:relationship, url: relationships_path, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :followed_id, value: @user.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

similarly a partial _unfollow.html.erb with the value of the submit button changed to `Unfollow`.

(Although I am not a big fan of hidden fields. You could set up nested routes too.)

So now you can have a method in your model say `is_following(user)` , which would check if the `current_user` and the `other_user have a relationship.
And say in the show page

```
<% if current_user.is_following(other_user) %>
  <%= render 'unfollow' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'follow' %>
<% end %>
```

And then you need your `js.erb` files to handle the JavaScript response for you.
In this case name `create.js.erb` and `edit.js.erb`
for example:

```
$("some_selector_name).html("<%= j render('shared/follow') %>")
```

Regarding the state machine (which i feel is kindof overkill for a two state relation) can be used in your users model **maybe** *like*

```
state_machine :state, initial: :unfollow
  event :confirm_follow do
    transition to: :follow, from: :unfollow
  end
  state :follow do
    def is_following?(user) 
      // do some checks
      //!!relationships.find(user.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! you have been absolutely brilliant spending so much time with me helping me learn JS and ROR. Tonight has been invaluable for my learning!